# How would a Kotlin notebook work when kotlin is a compiled language?

Tags: kotlin, jupyter-notebook

I tried [the Kotlin notebook extension](https://github.com/ligee/kotlin-jupyter) and I wonder what is going under the hood.
I have used notebooks with python and because python is an interpreted language it seems natural that it works in the notebook.

[image: Kotlin notebook]

My understanding is that after writing the Kotlin code I need to compile it (No?) before I execute it. But in notebook, if I create a class in one cell, I am able to instantiate an object in the next cell and I can't figure out how is this working.

EDIT:
It appears there are [IPYTHON kernels](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) for many of the compiled languages. However the question remains "How do compiled programming languages work in the interactive jupyter notebook environment"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kotlin has a special scripting mode (apart from the ordinary compiled mode), we often name a Kotlin script with the suffix `.kts`.

You can try this with a command line Kotlin compiler:

- Write `println("hello world")` in `a.kts`
- Run `kotlinc -script a.kts`

And you'll see `hello world` printed on screen.

If you have IntelliJ IDEA, try right-clicking on a `.kts` file and select `Run` option. You'll see command line output.

> How do compiled programming languages work in the interactive jupyter notebook environment?

There's nothing to do with "compiled" here. This is a special function of Kotlin compiler (running kotlin codes as script).
Not all languages have such feature. This isn't general-purpose.

Comment: Hi, thanks, your answer made things clear. I would definitely try the `kotlinc`.

Comment: You can install it via a tool called `sdk` provided by sdkman.io, or download a zip containing `kotlinc` on the Kotlin GitHub release

Answer (score 0):

One could argue that there's no such thing as an interpreted language, but I won't go that far.

Interpretation is a technique for implementing a programming language. Many languages have multiple implementations and quite often these implementations use different techniques. For example, Java has a [ton of implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) and techniques used by them vary from ahead-of-time compilation + bytecode interpretation, ahead-of-time compilation + JIT bytecode-to-machinecode compilation, ahead-of-time source-to-machinecode compilation and pure interpretation. Some implementation use hybrid techiques.

Python also has [multiple implementations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations). They are mostly based on bytecode interpretation and bytecode-to-machine-code JIT compilation. As far as I know, there's no ahead-of-time to-machine-code compiler (it's not impossible to create such, but probably not really beneficent for Python). Python, by default, compiles the source code to bytecode in memory on first run and dumps the bytecode to `*.pyc` files. On second run, it loads the bytecode from disk. Then it interprets the bytecode in memory. So Python also, typically, has a compilation phase, it's just not as visible.

So, what do people mean when they say "interpreted language"? Typically, it means that some language has either one implementation, or one *leading* implementation which is much more popular then the others (like CPython) and that leading implementation offers an interpreter. It doesn't mean that there are no ahead-of-time compilers for such language, or that it's conceptually impossible to create such. It also doesn't mean that other languages which are typically implemented with ahead-of-time compilers cannot be interpreted.

Given any programming language and an implementation in form of an ahead-of-time compiler, you can create a simple "interpreted" implementation by wrapping a compiler invocation and program execution (either direct or through an interpreter) in a single shell script or a simple helper program. You can save the binary/artifact in `/tmp`, for instance. If you have access to the compiler in form of a library (as opposed to the CLI program), and the compiler exposes an appropriate interface, you can skip the disk I/O step and write the compiler output to memory. It may be a bit faster and a bit less problematic, but conceptually the difference isn't big.

Kotlin Jupyter kernel is implemented that way. It uses a not-yet-stable, but documented solution sometimes called ["KotlinScript"](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md). I haven't read the appropriate source code (feel free to do so), but as you already know, the only thing it has to do is to transform (compile) the code and then execute it (exactly like in case of Python). How does KotlinScript achieve this goal (whether it invokes the compiler through a subprocess or using a Java library, whether it writes the output to disk...) is an implementation detail.